# PHP browser library (with curl maybe)

Tags: php, file, url, browser, web-crawler

Can anyone suggest any good cURL based PHP browser / spider / crawler / http / file download libraries..?

I just want to have a tool for downloading content from URLs, like I would do with `implode('', file(url))` or `file_get_contents()`, but it should support timeouts, HTTP code responses, custom headers etc.

cURL is awesome, I've been using it for a while in a function I created, but I want an encapsulated 3rd party library. Sure there must be such.. I made a search, but I couldn't find exactly what I wanted.

Comment: What functions are you looking for in that "browser library"

Comment: Just a `fetchURL()` with the ability to pass headers and set timeout is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my own pretty decent function using cURL: http://pastebin.com/4CPaCfMm

It works, but I just though I could search for a more advanced OOP tool that I could use in my projects, that would get maintained and furthur developed - a library.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/
Is a php library for parsig/downloading content.

Comment: No, it is just a DOM parser, not downloader.

Comment: You did not get my point, simplehtmldom parses the returned content which is fetched with `$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');` <-- this is what I need, an advanced "fetcher".

Comment: you can download images with this parser

Comment: I already use phpQuery as a DOM parser.

Answer (score 0):

I was using [PHPCrawl](http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/) for my web crawler project. It is purely standalone library, without dependency of cURL.

It provides functions to recursively download content of given URL, and support pattern matching and timeout. Then you can do whatever you want with the retrieved URL content. Oh yes, it can give you the HTTP response status. But not sure for custom headers.